# I want to get from the database all planes where the number of business class seats is more than 20

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get from the database all planes where the number of business class seats is more than 20. Diagram of database here: [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC1SH.png)

I already write JOIN request from db to get all airplanes with all seats

```
SELECT 
Aircrafts.aircraft_code AS aircraft_code,
Seats.fare_conditions AS class
FROM Aircrafts
JOIN Seats
ON Aircrafts.aircraft_code = Seats.aircraft_code
```

And I write Count request to get all aircrafts with defined aircraft_code

```
WITH additional_table AS(
SELECT 
Aircrafts.aircraft_code AS aircraft_code,
Seats.fare_conditions AS class
FROM Aircrafts
JOIN Seats
ON Aircrafts.aircraft_code = Seats.aircraft_code 
)

SELECT Count(*) FROM additional_table 
WHERE aircraft_code = '319' AND class = 'Business'
```

Comment: Why have you tagged [[tag:postgresql]] and [[tag:tsql]]? PostgreSQL doesn't use Transact-SQL.

Comment: Use HAVING, the group wise where condition: HAVING COUNT(*) > 20